# Перенос на виртуальный сервер(Apache Tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet, развертывание

Здравствуйте, недавно столкнулся с проблемой: написал сервер tomcat, но работает он только на локалке. В этом деле я новичок и хотел спросить, как заставить мой сервер работать дистанционно(чтобы я мог зайти на него с другого компьютера)? Писал сам сервер в InteliJ IDEA EAP.

Comment: Могу вас огорчить, но Tomcat написали не вы, а Apache. Сервер работает только в локальной сети? Или же только на вашем компьютере? Или же вы хотите, чтобы люди из интернета могли зайти на ваш сервер? Есть ли у вас роутер или вы используете прямое соединение с интернетом?

Comment: @ArchDemon Я использую роутер, под "локалкой" я имел ввиду localhosе

Comment: @AlexSukhobrusov, надо полагать, что вы не `Tomcat` переписали, а сделали `java` программу в виде `jar` или `war` и запускаете её через `Tomcat` на `localhost`? И вам надо тоже самое, только на `VPS` так, чтобы запускать/открывать прогу по адресу типа `http://123.123.123.123` вместо `http://localhost`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да, вы правы

Comment: @AlexSukhobrusov, написал в ответ что нужно сделать. Деталей там масса. Лично у меня в первый раз это заняло 10 часов копания гугла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно:

1. Где-то раздобыть сервер. Например виртуальный `VPS` арендовать у хостера.
2. Установить на сервере нужный софт. `Java`, `Tomcat`.
3. Запустить на сервере `Tomcat`
4. Положить ваш `*.war` файл в папку `Tomcat`.
5. `Tomcat` автоматически запустит программу. И к ней можно будет обращаться по адресу сервера.